# AngularJS ng-repeat and li lists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
$scope.features =
    {
    "administrative": [
        { id: 1, val: "Country"},
        { id: 2, val: "Province"},
        { id: 3, val: "Locality"},
        { id: 4, val: "Neighborhood"},
        { id: 5, val: "Land parcel"}
    ],
    "landscape": [
        { id: 1, val: "Man made"},
        { id: 2, val: "Natural"}
    ]
};

<ul>
    <li ng-model="features" ng-repeat="feature in features">{{feature.i}}</li>
</ul>
```

Using AngularJS I am trying to loop through my data and create firstly a list with `administrative` and `landscape` instead I seem to be getting an output of the children data within each parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To iterate over keys of objects, you need to use the following syntax, as explained in [the documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

> (key, value) in expression – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.
>
> For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(featureName, featureArray) in features">{{ featureName }}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want each of the item in features to be displayed first then you have to use:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-model="xyz" ng-repeat="(key, values) in features">{{ key }}</li>
</ul>
```

I think something like [**this demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FSwO2E9Sn8JPPENjBulR?p=preview) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close, the main part of ng-repeat has to be an array, so specifying features, confuses it, but features.administrative would work. Then inside your interpolation tags {{}} you specify fields of the object. Also, you do not need the ng-model.

Try this.

```
<li ng-repeat="feature in features.administrative">{{feature.val}}</li>
<li ng-repeat="feature in features.landscape">{{feature.val}}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, how would I be able to only show a list with `administrative` and `landscape`? Am I right that they are the keys of this data?

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in features">{{key}}</li>`